# How to handle $post_[] on all inputs

Tags: php, forms, post

What's the ideal way to handle an input form with multiple values, without going through each `$POST_['inputname']` individually?

For example, let's say I have an invite form like this:

```
<form id="input-form" action="" method="post" >

   <input id="email_1" name="email_1" />
   <input  id="role_1"  name="role_1" />

   <input id="email_2" name="email_2" />
   <input  id="role_2"  name="role_2" />

   <input id="email_3"  name="email_3" />
   <input  id="role_3"  name="role_3" />

</form>
```

Ideally, I'd like to create two arrays with the data, one for the email addresses and another for the roles

The resulting arrays would look like this:

```
$emailArray = array(
   'email1' => "emailOneData", 
   'email2' => "emaiTwoData",
   'email3' => "emaiThreeData",
);
$RoleArray = array(
   'role1' => "roleOneData", 
   'role2' => "roleTwoData",
   'role3' => "roleThreeData",
);
```

Not sure what the best way of splitting the data is though. Also I don't really want to do something like this:

```
$_POST['email_1']
$_POST['email_2']
$_POST['email_3']
.....
```

Comment: You'll have to because $_POST is an associative array

Comment: Yes but couldn't you create two new arrays and simply replace the keys with incrementing values and swap the values and keys on another?

Comment: Why do you want associative arrays like that? Why not ordinary index arrays like `$emailArray = array('emailOneData', 'emailTwoData', 'emailThreeData')`?

Comment: can you insert rows into the DB from an indexed array like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use instead an $_POST Array.

```
   <form id="input-form" action="" method="post" >

   <input id="email_1" name="email[]" />
   <input  id="role_1"  name="role[]" />

   <input id="email_2" name="email[]" />
   <input  id="role_2"  name="role[]" />

   <input id="email_3"  name="email[]" />
   <input  id="role_3"  name="role[]" />

</form>
```

After this you got an array like this:

```
echo'<pre>';
print_r($_POST['email']);
print_r($_POST['role']);
echo'</pre>';
```

Of course you still have to escape your input in dependency of your use.

After this you can use a normal foreach on the array.

```
$mails=array();
$count=count($_POST['role']);
for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){
   $mails["email_".$i]=$_POST['role'][$i];
}
```

Comment: -1: This won't contain names as he wants. It would contain indexed associative array

Comment: It is better to store the `count()` value to a variable and use it in for loop condition

Comment: Good point, I guess else it gets evaluated every iteration, correct?

Comment: Yeah, so it takes more time to execute

Comment: Hey this returns an Undefined index error from the $_POST